# ASP.NET MVC using more than 1 DataContext Insert Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, crud, datacontext

So i recently want to try using more than 1 database

my main problem is the attribute on 1st and 2nd entities is different, so for example in 1st entities sample_table1 contain: "member_id" and "member_code" and the 2nd entities sample_table_2 contain "student_id" and "student_code" it's just the naming, the value of the attribute is same, so member_id = student_id, member_code = student_code

Example:

Controller

```
private MyEntities db = new MyEntities ();

//not sure know by add this one, my controller can connect 2 database, but the intellisense is working when i'm using db2 class
private MyEntities2 db2 = new MyEntities2 ();

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateSomething(sample_table1 sample_table1, sample_table2 sample_table2)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       //insert data to 1st Entities
       db.sample_table1.Add(sample_table1);
       db.SaveChanges();

       //insert data to 2nd Entities
       "???" // because the attribute name on 2nd entities is not the same as the 1st entities, i cannot using either sample_table1 & sample_table2
       db2.SaveChanges();

   }
}
```

Views

```
@model 1st_entites_data_model.Models.sample_table1
// i don't know for sure but the 2nd entities data model won't appear when i add view    

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Something";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateSomething", "test", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    //i'm using only the 1st entities, because there is no need for user input the same data value twice
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.sample_table1.member_id)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sample_table1.member_id)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.sample_table1.member_code)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sample_table1.member_code)

}
```

i cannot change the 2nd entities name because somebody else is making the 2nd entities, and i cannot edit the database structure...

Thank You Very Much...

Comment: Is it the connection strings that cause trouble? What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [automapper](http://automapper.org/) to transfer data from first to second entity.After that your code will be:

...

```
   db.sample_table1.Add(sample_table1);
   db.SaveChanges();

   //insert data to 2nd Entities
   var sample_table2 = Mapper.Map<sample_table2>(sample_table1);
   db2.sample_table_2.Add(sample_table2);
   db2.SaveChanges();
```

...

Comment: does it map all the structure, because i don't want to get all the attribute, basically only some attribute from the 1st entities to the 2nd entities

Comment: you can configure this. There is ignore in settings